# Group action problem.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-actions

I've formed up a group $G=\{(1),(34),(12)(34),(124)\}$ acting on a set $X= \{1,2,3,4\}$. Knowing the axioms for a group action, that is:

1. (Compatibility with identity):
   $e*x=x$ for all $x\in X$
2. (Compatibility with group operation):
   $g_1*(g_2*x) = (g_1*g_2)*x,\;\;\forall x\in X,\;\;g_1, g_2\in G$.

I tried checking if the axioms were met. Since, the identity element $(1)$ exists within the group, I supposed that the first axiom was met. 
For the second axiom I did the following:

Let $b = (34)$ and $c = (12)(34)$, the elements of $G$. For the second axiom to be met $b*(c*x)=(b*c)*x,\;\; x\in X$.

Left Hand Side:
$b*(c*x)$, let $x=3$, element of set $X$.
Since in $(12)(34)$, $3$ is mapped to $4$, it implies $(c*x)=4$. Then, $b*(4)$ from which I get $3$ again.

Right Hand Side:
$(b*c)*x$, let $x=3$, element of $X$.
$(b*c)$ gives $(12)$ implying $(12)*x$ from which I get $3$. Hence LHS=RHS.

I thought I proved the group action, but was wrong, the second axiom was not met for other values of $x$. 
I would really appreciate some help. Is there something wrong with the group I used or is the entire work just wrong?

Comment: Are you sure that this $G$ is in fact a group...? Hint: is it closed under composition of permutations?

Comment: Furthermore, the identity element being in the group isn't enough to ensure that it acts as the identity on the set $X$ under the group action - this is something you need to check, and will depend on how you've defined your group action! Obviously in this case, since $G \leq Sym(X)$, this is fairly clearly the case, but with more complicated group actions it isn't necessarily immediately clear, so you should explicitly check it rather than just saying "the identity exits in the group so $e\cdot x = x$ for all $x \in X$"; $G$ wouldn't even be a group if it had no identity element!

Comment: @ah1195o, thanks. Indeed I've checked that it is closed under the composition of permutations and of course that the identity does exist, well according to my work that is.

Comment: @ah1195o , sorry, I've rechecked my work and somehow, I've just discovered that the inverse of (124) does not exist in G.

Comment: Not only that, @Sai82. Also, $\;(124)(34)=(1243)\notin G\;$ and etc....

Comment: @DonAntonio thanks, there is in fact a lot more work to be done.

Comment: If you replace (124) with (12), then you'll have a group.

Comment: @DonAntonio , If I do fix the problem with my group G, will the group action exist then?

Comment: Indeed so, @Sai82...if you mean the natural, "standard" action.

Comment: I've finally found the group I needed... and a whole lesson learned, thanks.